# Is the following phrase "He disappointed me of the money he promised" correct?

Tags: sentence-usage

Is the sentence "he disappointed me of the money" correct?  Are there similar examples with the verb disappoint in English?

Comment: No, it's wrong. You can't disappoint a person **of** anything. You would have to explain what you mean. **He disappointed me by failing to return the money he owed** or similar.

Comment: You may be confused with "Dispossessed" , which is sometimes used humorously to mean "robbed" or "relieved" , like "The robber Dispossessed me of my watch" ; Disappointed is wrong !

Comment: @RonaldSole - You can disappoint someone of something, but [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disappointed+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows that the usage has declined sharply since the early 19th century.

Comment: @KateBunting I bow to the Ngram's evidence. Although I hail from the first half of the last century and am reasonably well read in the classics, I have never come across it, and think that it may safely be described as archaic.

Comment: He then commissioned Maggy to return with his replies, and gave her the shilling of which the failure of her supplemental enterprise would have disappointed her otherwise.
Charles Dickens Little Dortit chapter 22

Comment: Disappointed her of the shilling

Comment: Yes - _Little Dorrit_ was written in the mid-19th century, when this usage was more common. As Ronald says, it is uncommon enough today to sound odd.